# Agregar dato a un array de objetos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas noches tengo una duda, suponiendo que tengo lo siguiente:

```
const obj = [{id:1,nombre:'fulanito'},{id:2,nombre:'menganito'}]
```

Y quiero agregar un valor donde está el id:1 'por ejemplo', digamos que quede al final `{id:1,nombre:'fulanito',apellido:'perez'}` si quiero agregar **apellido:perez** al indice 0 de forma dinamica, como puedo hacerlo? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿A que te refieres exactamente con "de forma dinámica"?

Answer (score 2):

No se que significaría exactamente "dinámico", de cualquier manera si el criterio es buscar un indice, se puede hacer directamente, como han dicho `obj[0].apellido = "Perez"`, si el criterio es el valor de una propiedad hay que buscar el valor de la propiedad en todos los elementos, una forma sería:

```js
const obj = [{id: 1,nombre: 'fulanito'}, {id: 2,nombre: 'menganito'}];


function agrega_apellido(id, apellido) {


  obj.forEach((e, i) => { // <-- recorremos cada objeto 

    if (e.id === id) { // <-- Suponemos que siempre existe la propiedad "id"

      e.apellido = apellido;

    }

  })


}

agrega_apellido(1, "Perez");

console.log(obj);
```

En cuanto al orden de las propiedades, hay que asumir que los objetos literales no tienen orden, `{a:1, b:2}` es según el standard, igual a `{b:2,a:1}` ese hecho es lo que hace difícil la comparación de objetos.

Lo mismo pero mas corto sería:

```js
const obj = [{id: 1,nombre: 'fulanito'}, {id: 2,nombre: 'menganito'}];

const agrega_apellido = (id, apellido) => obj.forEach(e=> e.id === id && (e.apellido = apellido));

agrega_apellido(1, "Perez");

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Se hace asi:

```
obj[X].apellido = "perez"
```

donde X es el numero del objeto en tu array.

Hay que puntualizar que deberias de quitar el `const`, pues si lo vas a modificar y va a ser dinamico, de nada sirve que lo declares como constante.

Comment: Realmente no hay que quitar el const porque no estas modificando la variable sino el contenido del array

Comment: de hecho te recomiendo que te lo vuelvas a mirar sobretodo el apartado de array. y tu ejemplo está mal ya que obj[X] no le va a funcionar ya que el id de dentro del objeto no tiene nada que ver con la posición del array.

Comment: de nuevo... https://medium.com/@tatymolys/var-let-y-const-donde-cuando-y-por-qu%C3%A9-d4a0ee66883b

Comment: @Srsole en la primera documentación a la que [haces referencia](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp) al sugerir quitar `const`, dice claramente: *Always use `const` when you declare: ·A new Array ...*, es decir, *Siempre usar `const` cuando declares: ·Un Array ...*. Por lo tanto tú mismo te contradices. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Creo que la mejor opción es hacer un find:

```
const array = [{id:1,nombre:'fulanito'},{id:2,nombre:'menganito'}];
const fulanito = array.find(item => item.id === 1);
fulanito.apellido = "perez";
```

Si quieres añadir una lista de apellidos ordenados al array que ya tienes puedes hacer un for directamente:

```
const array = [{id:1,nombre:'fulanito'},{id:2,nombre:'menganito'}];
const apellidos = ['perez', 'perez']
array.forEach((item, idx) => {
   item.apellido = apellidos[idx];
})
```

eso ya depende de como lo quieras hacer tu, pero recuerda que si pillas un objeto de un array con un find por ejemplo se mantiene la referencia y si haces un cambio allí se cambia en el array.

Comment: En ningún caso se pide ordenar. Para que buscas el contenido? no se pregunta. un For? para agregar un atributo a un objeto no es necesario montar tanta historia.

Comment: En ningún caso estoy diciendo ordenar, estoy buscando el contenido porque el quiere añadir el apellido en el item con id 1 exactamente. he dado dos opciones una dinámicamente y la otra de uno en concreto